# Understanding Vimscripts Through an Easy Example

Tags: vimscript

I want to write a function which takes two strings **this** and **that** as its arguments and replaces all instances of **this** with **that**.

So the function should look like:

```
function! ReplaceThisWithThat(this, that)
       "Main Stuff
.
.
.
endfunction
```

Can somebody please help?

Comment: That might be a dumb question but why do you want to create such a function? The `substitute` command isn't satisfying enough for you or it's just for vimscript training purpose?

Comment: It's just for training purpose.

Comment: oh ok then have fun with that :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it very simply with:

```
function! ReplaceThisWithThat(this, that)
    execute "%s/" . a:this . "/" . a:that . "/g"
endfunction
```

Which will substitute every occurrence of `a:this` with `a:that` in the whole buffer.

If you want to perform that substitution on the content of some variable or register, you can use `substitute()` in your function:

```
function! ReplaceThisWithThat(something, this, that)
    return substitute(a:something, a:this, a:that, "g")
endfunction
```

which doesn't make much sense.

That said, everything you need to know is in `:help eval.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Function arguments have `a:` prefix.

```
function! ReplaceThisWithThat(this, that)
       "Main Stuff
 echo a:this "named argument 'this'
 echo a:that

 echo a:0 " postioned first argument
endfunction
```

Comment: But echo is not going to make any replacements for me right? How do I do the search and replace thingy with variables?

Comment: @caffeinemachine your title queston only asks about how arguments work, which this answer covers. It isn't very clear from your question that you mostly care about the actual replacement. Perhaps consider re-wording your title and adding clarification to the question.

Comment: I agree. The title and the body of the question were rather different. But the problem is now solved.